# ci-merchant authorize.net AIM - complete working example

Tags: php, authorize.net, ci-merchant

Can anyone point me in the example of documentation for using the authorize.net AIM driver. I have the spark successfully installed (ci-merchant), but I am having trouble figuring out

- how to pass a payment amount for a simple transaction,
- why my **response->`message()`;** is returning an empty string.

The documentation for this driver should be at http://ci-merchant.org/gateways/authorize-net-aim.html but is not.

Any help on pointing me towards a working example of using this driver would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried following the basic tutorial at http://ci-merchant.org/ ? There is no driver specific documentation at this time, but they are all pretty similar. Can you try echoing `print_r($response)` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: I guess that sort of answers my question, The only documentation i can find is for paypal. So I'm assuming that as long as I follow the same guidelings as in `code
  $params = array(
   'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'),
   'currency' => 'USD',
      'card_no' => $this->input->post('cc'),
      'exp_month' => $this->input->post('month'),
      'exp_year' => $this->input->post('year'),
      'csc' => $this->input->post('ccv'),
   'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
   'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name')
      ); ` I should be o.k.

Comment: Yes, all payment gateways have the same API, so that should work. Some have extra required fields, in that case you would get a helpful error in the response. Try it out and see what response you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
Merchant_response Object
(
    [_status:protected] => failed
    [_message:protected] => 
    [_reference:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => 
    [_redirect_url:protected] => 
    [_redirect_method:protected] => GET
    [_redirect_message:protected] => 
    [_redirect_data:protected] => 
)
```